# Media extensions sample metro bug?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, ms-media-foundation

Media extensions sample
This sample demonstrates how to use media extensions to apply effects to video, decode video, and create media streams using scheme handlers.

I just debug the sample. I choose one mpg file, the file duration is 4mins. the sdk app run ok, show two overlap block. but after about 1min40s, the sdk app crash. 
information like this: "Unhandled exception at 0x68A95B94 (mfcore.dll) in MediaExtensionsCPP.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x68A26A38."

I replace another file, the same error.
So I think the Microsoft sample have some bug. Does somebody have same problem? can share me the resolution method. thank you very much.

Comment: I find the reason of that issue. the dllmain.cpp for metro. The function is like this: HRESULT WINAPI DllCanUnloadNow()
{
    auto &module = Microsoft::WRL::Module<Microsoft::WRL::InProc>::GetModule();    
   return (module.Terminate()) ? S_OK : S_FALSE;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Media team has a fix that will be in the new release of the samples to address this issue. These are the instructions to fix the current samples:

We found a bug in the Media samples which cause DLLs to get unloaded too early. In the meantime you can add these lines to constructors/destructors of the source/stream classes in the MSDN samples:
 Note: This is not needed for classes which derive from RuntimeClass<> (ex: the scheme handler).

Constructor:
    auto module = ::Microsoft::WRL::GetModuleBase();
    if (module != nullptr)
    {
        module->IncrementObjectCount();
    }

Destructor:
    auto module = ::Microsoft::WRL::GetModuleBase();
    if (module != nullptr)
    {
        module->DecrementObjectCount();
    }